# C Programming: Initialize a 2D array of with numbers 1, 2, 3...etc

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, user-input

I am having trouble creating a 2D Array of a size defined by the user, with numbers 1, 2, 3.etc.

If the user chooses for example: `a = 2 and b = 2`, the program produces:

```
3 4

3 4
```

instead of:

```
1  2

3  4
```

My program looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int Array[a][b];
    int row, column;
    int count = 1;

/*User Input */
    printf("enter a and b \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

/* Create Array */
    for(row = 0; row < a; row++)
    {
        for(column = 0; column <b; column++)
        {
            Array[row][column] = count;
            count++;
        }
    }

/* Print Array*/
    for(row = 0; row<a; row++)
    {
        for(column = 0; column<b; column++)
        {
            printf("%d ", Array[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run a debugger .Have you defined your array size ,NO. You enter the array size after declaring it.Actually this question is not even worth answering.

Comment: int Array[a][b]; what is this??? int Array[2][2]; works fine.

Comment: Your code looks nicely formatted, that's a good thing, really!  One thing to improve is to consistently & always place spaces around operators.  You're doing `row < a`, `comumn <b`, and `column<b` at the moment.

Comment: Three upvotes on the answer and a upvote on the question too , I think I missed the golden opportunity to answer first and earn reputation. haha :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a, b;
```

variables `a` and `b` are uninitialized and their value is undetermined by C language

```
int Array[a][b];
```

You declare an array which has [a,b] size. The problem is that a and b are undetermined and using them at this point is undefined behavior.

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

you get `a` and `b` values -- but the `Array` remains the same!

**Simplest solution:** try to put Array declaration after `scanf`. Your compiler may allow it (I think C99 is required to do so).

Comment: @BillBailey You should thank him but this was sheer carelessness on your part. I mean, this is one of the very poor mistakes that one can do which is not a crime initially but the main part is not trying hard .

Answer (score 1):

Variable length array is not supported in c89 standard.

int `Array[a][b];` is meaningless. Because values of `a` and `b` is unknown at that time. so change it to `Array[2][2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your array size is not known at compile-time, you'll need to dynamically allocate the array after a and b are known.
like code as follows:

```
int **allocate_2D_array(int rows, int columns)
{
    int k = 0;
    int **array = malloc(rows * sizeof (int *) );

    array[0] = malloc(columns * rows * sizeof (int) );
    for (k=1; k < rows; k++)
    {
        array[k] = array[0] + columns*k;
        bzero(array[k], columns * sizeof (int) );
    }

    bzero(array[0], columns * sizeof (int) );

    return array;
}
```

Comment: that's not true, he doesn't *have to* declare the array through malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array size is not known at compile-time, you'll need to dynamically allocate the array after `a` and `b` are known.

Here's a link that describes how you can allocate the multi-dimensional array (really an array of arrays): http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Applying the example code from that link, you might do this:

```
int **Array; /* Instead of int Array[a][b] */

...

/* Create Array */
Array = malloc(a * sizeof(int *));
for(row = 0; row < a; row++)
{
    Array[row] = malloc(b * sizeof(int));
    for(column = 0; column <b; column++)
    {
        Array[row][column] = count;
        count++;
    }
}
```