# Warning: Expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(n)]’

Tags: c

Following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSpiral(int **M, int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2) {
  if (!((row1 <= row2) && (col1 <= col2)))
    return;
  int i;
  for (i = col1; i <= col2; i++)
    printf("%d ", M[row1][i]);
  for (i = row1; i <= row2; i++)
    printf("%d ", M[i][col2]);
  for (i = col2; i >= col1; i--)
    printf("%d ",M[row2][i]);
  for (i = row2; i >= row1; i--)
    printf("%d ",M[i][col1]);
  printSpiral(M,row1+1,row2-2,col1+1,col2-1);
}

int main() {
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int M[n][n];
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      scanf("%d",&M[i][j]);
  printSpiral(M,0,n-1,0,n-1);
  return 0;
}
```

gives following warning:

```
spiral.c: In function ‘main’:

spiral.c:26:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printSpiral’ from incompatible pointer     
type [enabled by default]
printSpiral(M,0,n-1,0,n-1);`

spiral.c:3:6: note: `expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[(sizetype)(n)]’`
void printSpiral(int **M, int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2) {
```

I have seen this warning for the first time. What does it mean?

Comment: can't do variable initialization on arrays. compiler misinterprets the type for M..

Comment: @amdixon: [You can now.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) The real problem here is that a 2D array is neither a pointer to a pointer nor compatible with functions that expect a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: There are a number of duplicates for this. I'll go digging...

Comment: And once again... ***Arrays ain't no pointers!***

Comment: @amdixon: [this code](http://pastebin.com/a24SjFnD) works fine

Comment: @H2CO3: I own Linden's "Expert C Programming", it seems I should read that _now_

Comment: yes just tried a VLA (and works ;)

Comment: @kamalbanga Or perhaps K&R C. Anyway, there's a really good and almost-exhaustive list around here on SO, if you search for it, you'll surely find some *trustworthy* recommendations for C books.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two problems with this code. First you are passing argument of `int (*)[(sizetype)(n)]` (pointer to an array of `n` integers, this is the type your 2D array `M` decays to when you pass it to a function) to your function which is expecting an argument of `int **`. Always remember ***Arrays are not pointers***.  One possible solution is you can change your function's first parameter to `int (*)[(sizetype)(n)]` type.

```
void printSpiral(int (*M)[n], int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2) {
```

But by doing this the second problem will comes into light and that is because of you declared `M` as variable length array and `n` is not known to the function. This issue can be resolved by passing `n` from `main` to your function and hence change your function definition to

```
void printSpiral(int n, int (*M)[n], int row1, int row2, int col1, int col2) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler wants to tell you that the functions expects a `int **`, but you provide it an argument of type `int (*)[(sizetype)(n)]`.

The first is a pointer to (the first element of an array of) `int *`, the second one is a pointer to an array/arrays of given length.

Compare what both means in memory and why this cannot work this way.

The solution would be to provide the function a pointer to one element an at least the total number of columns. (If you want the function to do bounds-checking, it needs the number of rows as well.) Then you have to calculate the indexes manually.

Answer (score -1):

you should know `int a[][]` is different from `int **a`,the first `a` is same to int (*a)[] which means a pointer which point a array;if you want to indicate a 2D array by `int **a`,please reference this:[C Programming: Initialize a 2D array of with numbers 1, 2, 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563075/c-programming-initialize-a-2d-array-of-with-numbers-1-2-3-etc/17563443#17563443)